# Ruby thread/fibre scheduling by time

Tags: ruby, multithreading, scheduling

Is it possible to specify how long a thread/fibre/continuation is run before yielding in Ruby 1.9.3? I'd like to implement priority for processes as relatively faster or slower running speed. Exactly how I do this is completely open right now.

Edit: I'll add that I'm not out to micromanage the scheduler. A controlled global slow down/speed up of each thread is enough.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-priority-3D

Comment: Yeah but priority doesn't necessarily work. "This is just hint for Ruby thread scheduler. It may be ignored on some platform", https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1169